# Find inverse of the parametric matrix

Tags: matrix

I want to calculate the bellow parametric matric but I faced with this error:
any suggestion??

```
Inverse::sing: Matrix {{-0.00950009,2.40002,0.000800379,0.0352495,1.80002,0.,5.00005,0.,0.0891225,0.,0.,0.},<<10>>,{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1.,0.,0.,0. +1. (0. +0.983822 kp1),0.,0.  +1. (0. -0.983822 ki1),0.}} is singular. >>

aa = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"-", "0.009500088916165429`"}], "2.400022463031266`", 
    "0.0008003791973611289`", "0.03524950511134242`", 
    "1.8000168472734495`", "0.`", "5.000046797981804`", "0.`", 
    "0.08912252068877918`", "0.`"},
{
RowBox[{"-", "4.249449196474859`"}], 
RowBox[{"-", "0.009498768792120273`"}], 
RowBox[{"-", "3.649526956972526`"}], 
RowBox[{"-", "3.649526956972526`"}], "0.05287713841368586`", "0.`", 
    "0.`", "4.999351995852775`", 
RowBox[{"-", "16.225880855349132`"}], "0.`"},
{"0.003709074329234499`", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.937029304227663`"}], 
RowBox[{"-", "0.001532232778509832`"}], "0.020643926858765697`", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.7027719781707472`"}], "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "1.9521443838076311`"}], "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.03479567997315629`"}], "0.`"},
{"0.00474993331287593`", 
RowBox[{"-", "1.1999831527265505`"}], "0.0006002843980208465`", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.06168787116649318`"}], 
RowBox[{"-", "0.8999873645449129`"}], "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "2.499964901513647`"}], "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.044560217665623264`"}], "0.`"},
{"3.3048211508553664`", "0.007387247278382584`", "2.838258164852256`",
     "2.838258164852256`", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.07050285121824781`"}], "0.`", "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "3.888024883359255`"}], "12.618961131833414`", "0.`"},
{"0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.0011499956801152495`"}], "7.290140160891896`*^-6", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.0015029426380361623`"}], "0.`", "0.`"},
{
RowBox[{"-", "1.2195121951219514`*^6"}], "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", 
    "1.645874640407881`*^6", 
RowBox[{"-", "717.3601147776184`"}], "1.`", "3.245667357776069`", 
RowBox[{"-", "47613.70639510816`"}]},
{"0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "1.2195121951219514`*^6"}], "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", 
    "58672.418203339104`", 
RowBox[{"-", "1.`"}], 
RowBox[{"-", "717.3601147776184`"}], "0.01574336195873491`", 
    "1.335656417295498`*^6"},
{"4.3756666695771585`*^-6", "0.0008662027753442101`", 
    "8.633072077814393`*^-6", "8.633072077814393`*^-6", 
RowBox[{"-", "0.0001255700848391878`"}], "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "3.184713375796178`*^-7"}], "0.`"},
{"0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", "0.`", 
RowBox[{"-", "1.`"}], "0.`"}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
   "Columns" -> {{Center}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
    "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
    "ItemsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.7]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
    "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}], "", ")"}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
    MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\)
bb = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[{
{"0.`"},
{"0.`"},
{"0.`"},
{"0.`"},
{"0.`"},
{"0.0061104764986965225`"},
{"0.`"},
{"0.`"},
{"0.`"},
{"0.`"}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
   "Columns" -> {{Center}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
    "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
    "ItemsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.7]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
    "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}], "", ")"}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
    MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\);   o = ( {
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0}
 } );   m = ( {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}
 } );   s = ( {
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 } );  v = t = ( {
 {0, 0}
 } ); e = Transpose[( {
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
 } )];    f = Transpose[( {
 {1, 0, 0, 0}
 } )];  c = ( {
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
 } );
 g = ( {
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 } );

t = Partition[{aa, o, m, v, s, t}, 2];
a = ArrayFlatten[t];

j = Transpose[( {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
} )];
l = Partition[{j, bb, 0, 0, kd/(Cos[\[Beta]] sayr), 0}, 2];
b = ArrayFlatten[l];

k = ( {
{kp1, ki1, 0, 0},
{0, 0, kp2, ki2}
} );
i = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}];


ac = Inverse[i + b.k.g].(a - b.k.c) 
 Inverse[ac ]
```

Comment: What part of "is singular" did you not understand?

Comment: `t = Partition[{aa, o, m, v, s, t}, 2]` is an instant infinite recursion error.

Comment: I want to calculate  ac matrix but inverse of this matrix not calculate.

Comment: …and a singular matrix does not have an inverse. Where did you get this matrix, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler setting:

```
mat = {{a, a}, {a, a}}; Inverse[mat]
Inverse::sing: Matrix {{a,a},{a,a}} is singular. >>
```

This gives the error because the matrix does not have an inverse. If you wish, you can find the Moore-Penrose inverse (or pseudo-inverse) using:

```
PseudoInverse[mat]
```